# Print float variable to IEEE format in Trace32

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

In my code I have the following variable that I want to display in my log

```
t_f32 tx_float_to_1x16_send_data[15];
```

In my cmm script I tried different ways to display my variable but trace32 seems to only manage hex, decimal and binary but not IEEE

```
PRINT VAR.VALUE(tx_float_to_1x16_send_data[0])
PRINT %Decimal VAR.VALUE(tx_float_to_1x16_send_data[0])
PRINT FORMAT.DECIMAL(8.,VAR.VALUE(tx_float_to_1x16_send_data[0]))
```

I only found one way to display IEEE but it works with an adress and I don't know how to apply it to a variable

```
PRINT DATA.FLOAT("IEEE",D:0x800B2C)
```

Note : when using VAR.VIEW in debug mode, Trace32 is perfectly capable to format the data as a float

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess this should work:

```
PRINT Data.Float("IEEE",Var.ADDRESS(tx_float_to_1x16_send_data[0]))
```